# Como crear y rellenar una matriz según la lectura de cada linea de un archivo?

Tags: python, funciones, archivo, numpy, matriz

Se​ ​necesita​ ​crear​ ​un​ ​programa​ ​para​ ​generar​ ​las​ ​estadísticas​ ​de​ ​las​ ​palabras​ ​en​ ​un​ ​texto.​

​
Por​ ​ejemplo,​ ​a​ ​partir​ ​del​ ​siguiente texto:

Con​ ​la​ ​ayuda​ ​de​ ​un​ ​grupo​ ​de​ ​amigos​ ​y​ ​de​ ​valientes​ ​aliados​ ​Frodo​ ​emprende​ ​un​ ​peligroso​ ​viaje​ ​con​ ​la

misión​ ​de​ ​destruir​ ​el​ ​​Anillo​​ ​Único​ ​Pero​ ​el​ ​Señor​ ​Oscuro​ ​​Sauron​​ ​quien​ ​creara​ ​el​ ​​Anillo​​ ​envía​ ​a​ ​sus

servidores​ ​para​ ​perseguir​ ​al​ ​grupo​ ​Si​ ​​Sauron​​ ​lograra​ ​recuperar​ ​el​ ​​Anillo​​ ​sería​ ​el​ ​final​ ​de​ ​la​ ​Tierra

Media​ ​Ganadora​ ​de​ ​cuatro​ ​Oscars​ ​este​ ​inmortal​ ​relato​ ​sobre​ ​el​ ​bien​ ​y​ ​el​ ​mal​ ​la​ ​amistad​ ​y​ ​el​ ​sacrificio

te​ ​transportará​ ​a​ ​un​ ​mundo​ ​más​ ​allá​ ​de​ ​tu​ ​imaginación

Ahora​ ​implemente:
**La​ ​función​ ​​cargarArchivo(nombre),​ ​​que​ ​leerá​ ​el​ ​texto​ ​desde​ ​el​ ​archivo​ ​​nombre​​ ​y​ ​creará​ ​una​​ ​matriz​ ​M​ ​de​ ​NumPy​ ​(con dtype='U20')​ ​​donde​ ​cada​ ​fila​ ​representa​ ​una​ ​línea,​ ​y​ ​cada​ ​columna,​ ​una​ ​palabra​ ​de​ ​dicha​ ​línea.​ ​Si​ ​la​ ​línea​ ​tiene​ ​menos de​ ​30​ ​palabras,​ ​las​ ​celdas​ ​restantes​ ​deben​ ​ser​ ​llenadas​ ​con​ ​un​ ​string​ ​vacío.​ ​Cada​ ​línea​ ​del​ ​archivo​ ​está​ ​limitada​ ​por​ ​​'\n'​. Cada​ ​palabra​ ​está​ ​separada​ ​por​ ​un​ ​espacio​ ​en​ ​blanco.​ ​​**

Mi código hasta el momento presentando algunos errores y a falta de ciertas condiciones es el siguiente:

```
  def cargarArchivo(nombre):
  f = open(nombre,"r")
  filas = 0
  for linea in f:
    filas +=1
    palabras = linea.strip().split(" ")
    M = np.empty((filas,len(palabras)),dtype = "U20")
    filas,columnas = M.shape
    for i in range(filas):
      for j in range(columnas):
      M[i,j] = palabras[j]
  return M
```

El problema es que no se como hacer que la matriz se conforme de las 5 filas que representan cada linea que tiene el archivo. La ejecución del codigo es incompleta y no se que hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No queda claro qué hacer con líneas de más de 30 palabras. Ya que se menciona que si hay menos de 30 palabras deben rellenarse con espacios, asumo que la matriz M ha de tener obligatoriamente 30 columnas (y por tanto si en una línea hay más de 30 palabras hay que quedarse solo con las 30 primeras e ignorar el resto).

Tu problema es que estás creando una nueva M en cada iteración del bucle, y rellenándola con lo que has leído en la última línea. Al salir del bucle sólo tendrás copias repetidas de esa última línea.

La matriz `M` debería crearse antes de entrar al bucle que la rellena. El problema es que en ese punto todavía no sabemos cuántas líneas tiene el fichero.

Por tanto creo que lo más sencillo sería comenzar por leer el archivo a una serie de listas (una lista cuyos elementos sean a su vez listas, cada elemento de la lista externa representa una línea y cada elemento de la interna las palabras de esa línea), para después crear la matriz M (ahora ya sabremos cuántas líneas tiene, y las columnas son 30)  y finalmente en otro bucle ir pasando palabras de la lista de listas incialmente leida a la matriz.

Por ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np

def cargarArchivo(nombre):
  lista = []

  # Leer inicialmente el fichero
  with open(nombre,"r") as f:
    for linea in f:
      lista.append(linea.strip().split())

  # Crear la matriz 
  filas = len(lista)
  M = np.empty((filas, 30), dtype="U20")

  # Rellenar la matriz con lo leido del fichero
  for i in range(filas):
    for j in range(min(30, len(lista[i]))):
       M [i,j] = lista[i][j]
      
  return M
```

Al crear la matriz ya automáticamente tiene todas sus entradas pre-inicializadas con cadenas vacías, por lo que no necesitamos añadir éstas si las líneas son más cortas. El truco está en `for j in range(min(30, len(lista[i])))`. La función `min` te dará cuál es el menor de estos dos números: 30 o el número de palabras de la línea. Si la línea tiene por ejemplo 10 palabras, el resultado será 10, por lo que se `j` variará sólo entre 0 y 9 (dejando en el resto de `M` las cadenas vacías que ya había). Si en cambio la línea tiene por ejemplo 40 palabras, el resultado de `min()` será 30, por lo que `j` variará sólo entre 0 y 29, evitando así salirse del tamaño de la matriz (ignorando las palabras que sobren en la línea).

Comment: Muchas gracias, excelente aporte. Entendí perfectamente el error que estaba cometiendo y tu código corre perfectamente.